# Angular2-Highcharts: Click event on custom legend title

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

Below is the highcharts that I have created. I added a custom legend title, which gives me the count(2000). I am trying to have a click event on this 2000, but couldn't able to add it.

https://plnkr.co/edit/yzXLz7AIDoWa1Pzxxl4k?p=preview

My legend code:

```
 legend: {
                useHTML: true,
                enabled: true,
                align: 'center',
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                layout: 'vertical',
                x: 0,
              y:30,
                symbolHeight: 12,
                itemMarginBottom: 1,
                symbolWidth: 25,
                symbolRadius: 1,
                labelFormatter: function () {
                    return '<div style="width:180px"><span class="pull-left" style= "font-weight: 500; padding-bottom: 5px">' + this.name +
                    '</span><span class="pull-right" style= "font-weight: 500" >' + this.value +
                    '</span></div> ';
                },
                title: {
            text: ' Issues<br/><span style="font-size: 9px; color: #666; font-weight: normal">Total: 2000</span>' 
            //Click event on 2000 
            // call donut service's get total info. Need not have to pass any variable. 

        },


            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach onclick event on chart load event.

```
 template: `
    <chart  [options]="options" (load)="onChartLoad($event.context)">
    </chart>
```

In the component

```
onChartLoad(chart) {
  this.chart = chart;
  var t = chart.legend.title.element.children[0].children[1]
  t.onclick = () => this.onLegendTitleClick()
}

onLegendTitleClick() {
  console.log('title clicked', this)
}
```

example: https://plnkr.co/edit/kxEgwfV8iKUnBkIZlYxv?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot it works. For legend items click, I am trying to have "this" of class. But "this" has only chart properties but not the class. So I am unable to use the local variable of my service(this.donutservice). In the LegendTitleClick, I am able to get my local variable of the service. legendItemClick: function (e) {
                               console.log(this);
                                return false;
                            }

Comment: you need to correctly set up a service for the component. Set provider and the correct constructor with donut service. If you want to use this as the component in hc events you need to bind this properly. See example https://plnkr.co/edit/SWGSCNCLz7KJgjTDUaRY?p=preview

Comment: It really helped. Thanks

Comment: This may sound little crazy. It actually worked great in the morning, but suddenly it throws error in the console "Cannot read property 'children' of undefined".at DonutComponent.webpackJsonp.632.DonutComponent.onChartLoad (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:1025:55)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_DonutComponent0.handleEvent_7 (/AppModule/DonutComponent/component.ngfactory.js:83:34)

Comment: Did you get a chance to see my comment.

Comment: It looks like the dom element cannot be found - have you modified your legend? You can make it a little more safe by defining a css class to the dom element and then try to find that element https://plnkr.co/edit/W8Co6njuEW4Baa5lk9K3?p=preview

Comment: I didn't make any changes, but that is surprising why it stopped working all of a sudden. With the new suggestion that you have provided, I am getting compile error saying --"Property 'onclick' does not exist on type 'Eleme
nt'.)

Comment: Please have a look at this plnkr. Here I am unable to get the click event and the alert box(even in my application also). But couldn't able to get the service local variable(this.donutService) because "this" doesn't have the class properties.

Comment: any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look in to this.

Comment: I do not see any plunkr in your comment. As for the error, it is about typing in ts https://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/how-to-make-dynamic-chart-using-data-from-mysql-with-node-js-t36229/?hilit=%20socket

Comment: I am still facing the issue  "Property 'onclick' does not exist on type 'Element'".  at subtitle.onclick = (e) => this.onLegendTitleClick(e)

Comment: There is an issue if I have same component multiple times. As class is same it is creating an issue.

Comment: So the best solution would be use your initial idea. but in that case I am unable to get chart.legend.title.element.children[0].children[1], but in plnkr I am seeing it

Comment: Post a plunkr with the behavior you describe - It is impossible to debug with the actual code.